# How can I include a conditional order_by in django?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-1.10

I need to sort two parts of a queryset differently based on a boolean field.
- Rows that have bool_val == True should come first, and be sorted by date_a, ascending.
- Rows that have bool_val == False should come second, and be sorted by date_b, descending.

The closest I've gotten is

```
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
    sort_order=Case(
        When(bool_val=True, then=('date_a')), 
        default='date_b')
    ).order_by('-bool_val', 'sort_order')
```

But that sorts them all in the same order. If the value I needed to sort by were numerical, then I would multiply one set by -1 in my annotation, but they're date values, so that won't work.

I've also looked into creating two separate querysets and combining them, but union() isn't available until 1.11 and I have to support 1.10, and other methods of combining querysets that I've found either don't preserve order or don't result in a queryset (or both). (I'm not clear on whether union() preserves order or not, but it's moot, so I didn't dig into it much, either.) This has to be a django QuerySet object at the end.

Comment: You can use the negative sign on dates: `.order_by('bool_val', '-sort_order')`

Comment: Yes, but you can't do that conditionally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what ended up working:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    sort_order_true=Case(
        When(bool_val=True, then=('date_a')),
        default=None
    ),
    sort_order_false=Case(
        When(bool_val=False, then=('date_b')),
        default=None
    )
).order_by(
    'sort_order_true',
    '-sort_order_false',
)
```

Comment: Can we use a string field on When? like I want to use sort with a column named str_val which have a value in one record as `ASDF` that i need at first then by id 
`MyModel.objects.annotate(
    sort_order_true=Case(
        When(str_val="ASDF", then=(1)),
        default=0
    )
).order_by(
    'sort_order_true'
)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression to convert your datetimes into timestamps so that you can negate them.

For MySQL this is the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    sort_order=Case(
        When(bool_val=True, then=Func(F('date_a'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP')), 
        When(bool_val=False, then=Value(0) - Func(F('date_b'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP')), 
    )
).order_by('-bool_val', 'sort_order')
```

For PostgreSQL this is `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '<datetime>')`

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    sort_order=Case(
        When(bool_val=True, then=Func(F('date_a'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP')), 
        When(bool_val=False, then=Value(0) - Func('EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE', F('date_b'), function='EXTRACT', arg_joiner=' ')), 
    )
).order_by('-bool_val', 'sort_order')
```

A little cumbersome... and potentially slow. I have not tested this

Comment: This was a good thought but I ran into trouble with django trying to interpret `'EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE'` as a field name. I tried a couple variants but ended up finding a more elegant solution; see the answer I posted.

Comment: Thanks for proposing this solution. I had the same problem as @CharlotteMays and I ended up using this: `Extract('date_a', 'epoch')` in place of `Func(F('date_a'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP'))`

Answer (score 0):

This is an another approach for the same problem.
I think that this is would work better in null cases(if true or false is not available), but the previous could be helpful in some use cases.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

MyModel.objects.order_by(
    Coalesce(F('date_a'), F('date_b')).desc()
)
```